# como puedo tener multiple apps en Angular 4 con angularfire2

Tags: javascript, html, html5, angular

La documentación dice esto:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase, '**my-app-name'**)
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Como accedo a **my-app-name** en java script clasico accedo  mediante:

```
var otherAPP =firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase, '**my-app-name'**)
```

¿pero como en `angular 4`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero tenés que importar firebase al inicio del archivo donde necesites usarlo:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

Despues podes usar tu código:

```
const otherAPP = firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase2,'**my-app-name'**);
```

Si querés usarlo con un componente de angularfire2 (Ej. AngularFireAuth):

```
const auth = new  AngularFireAuth(otherAPP);
```

Comment: Por favor explica un poco tu codigo para que el OP lo entienda de mejor forma

Comment: hola. por favor mira [answer]. debes explicar que hace tu código para que tu respuesta sea mejor recibida.